# Как создать пересенную со значением другой переменной в её имени

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте!
Помогите пожалуйста создать переменную в имени которой будет значение другой переменной.
На пример:

```
var num = 45;
var result(здесь значение переменной num);
```

Comment: Это плохая идея, не надо так делать. Лучше скажите, какую задачу Вы таким образом пытаетесь решить?

Comment: а зачем это может понадобиться?

Comment: Я пытаюсь сделать генератор объектов с различными именами

Comment: В чем его назначение, если можно сделать функцию, которая возвращает объект, и присвоить результату любое имя?

Comment: Я делаю игру на JS. Таким образом создаю врагов. Само по себе они будут жить не долго. То есть появляются и изчезают менее чем через 30 секунд

Answer (score 2):

Можно, например, так:

```
window['result' + num] = 10;
```

Comment: А почему используется "window"?

Comment: @IvanIvanov, потому что это глобальный объект в браузере

Comment: Это вам надо копать js внутрь:) 
Если совсем просто, то глобальная переменная в js в браузере, это свойство объекта window

Comment: Вы можете создать свой объект. `var myObject = {}`. И задать ему свойство таким же образом. `myObject['result' + num] = 10;`

Comment: Всё понял! Большое спасибо :)